# Why do I keep getting error 500 (mySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, connection

I use the following php script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$link = mysql_connect('mywebsite', 'login', 'password'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully';
//Until here, everything is PERFECT, the Connection is established.

//The following piece of code spits out error 500: 
mysql_select_db("rates"); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `RateName` LIKE '%res%'"; 
if ($r=mysql_query($query, $link)) {

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
print "<p><h3>{$row['UtilityName']}>/h3>
{$row['RateName']}<br />
</p><hr />\n";
}
}
else {
print mysql_error($link)
}

mysql_close($link); 

 ?>
```

Comment: The `if($r =...)` is missing its closing `}`.

Comment: If you are seeing a 500 error, you _must_ check your web server's error log - enable error reporting if it isn't, and display on screen in development. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: You error will likely be something like `Unexpected T_ELSE...`

Comment: @Michael Berkowski I have corrected the if statement and included the error reporting in the code. I still have, quote: "This is a 500"

Comment: "This is a 500" is not an error generated by PHP. Look in your server's error log.

Comment: Hi @Michael Berkowski Thank you very much. My problem was exactly as you said: "some T_String."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
print mysql_error($link)
```

to

```
print mysql_error($link);
                        ^
```